# Application (MacVim) menubar went dark. How can I fix it?

Tags: macvim, title-bar

Recently, MacVim menubar decided to go dark:

It is very hard to read black text on a black menubar. How can I make the menubar grey again?

[image]

I am using MacVim 8.1.560 in MacOS X 10.12.6.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug when MacVim autoupgraded to Snapshot 152. I downgraded to Snapshot 150 and it works fine.